# How can I sort all the files in a folder by subfolder name, then by name?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search

I have a folder like this:

```
Main Folder
    subfolder 1
        image 1
        image 2
        image 3
    subfolder 2
        image 1
        image 2
        image 3
```

(actually, there are many more subfolders than this).

What I'd like to do is find some way to open up my photo viewer (Windows 10), and press the right arrow (next) continually, so as to go through all of them in the following order:

> s1 i1, s1 i2, s1 i3, s2 i1, s2 i2, s2 i3 etc

(Where s is subfolder and i is the image folder)...

I tried someone else's advice of searching for "*.*" in the main folder, but that way isn't in order.

Comment: +1 from me, good first question. I've updated your question to make it more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the parent folder. Type the search query `kind:picture`
In the results, sort by folder path (ascending).

This should arrange things as you need. If the name isn't correctly sorted, try the following in addition:

Do a secondary sort by "Name". This is done by holding SHIFT key and clicking on the Name header.
(FYI, doing it again does a reverse alpha sort.)
Preview the first image, and start a slideshow from within Windows Photo Viewer.

[image]

Comment: I love you. Also, how did you find this out? The "secondary sort" thing is very cool, but I've never heard of it.

Comment: I guess it's there since Windows 7, but not very much a known feature. But it's very useful one. [How to Sort by Date Modified (Descending) With Folders On Top?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/sort-by-date-modified-folders-on-top/)

Also, [Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is extremely useful.

Comment: But, how did you learn about the existence of this in the first place; is there a manual or something you read to get started on this (basic? advanced?) information?

Comment: I din't refer to any manual. I must have read it in a MS team blog or some forum. But I learnt it years ago so don't remember exactly. If you're looking for a manual/book, you'll like this: [MS Press Book](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2015/10/27/new-book-windows-10-inside-out/) I haven't bought that but Ed's books are usually good...